# Tibco Ems ha/dr solution

Tags: tibco, ems

I am new to Tibco EMS. We are currently using EMS 8 and are looking for a HA/DR option for it. I have heard of using Veritas for this purpose but that might not be our option for now.

So am looking for a open source alternative for veritas. I have also seen a few discussions where people suggested using rdbms/mysql for this but not sure how to do it.

Can someone please put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

For High Availability of EMS there are two modes you could consider. The first mode is called "Unshared State" and means that while two servers act as a fault-tolerant pair, their state (and thus the messages) are not shared between the two. The other mode is called "Shared State" in which the secondary server has access to the state in case the primary server goes down. I've seen both being used for different types of use cases, so you'll have to judge yourself which fits best.

If you want to go with a shared state, you'll have to make sure that both servers can access the state and generally speaking you'll have two options to do so:

- Filesystem
- Database

For the database option, there are a few databases that are supported by TIBCO. Please refer to the [EMS User Guide](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.4.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.4_users_guide.pdf), page 343 for more details on the supported databases as well as how to set up the data stores.

For the filesystem option, you'll have to make sure that your filesystem (either software or hardware) supports the four main characteristics that EMS needs:

1. Write Order
2. Synchronous Write Persistence
3. Distributed File Locking
4. Unique Write Ownership

*Source: [EMS User Guide](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.4.0/doc/pdf/TIB_ems_8.4_users_guide.pdf), page 520*

I've seen Veritas being used a lot, though I've also seen people use a clustered file system (like RedHat GFS or Oracle OCFS). Please be aware that depending on which option you choose, you want to properly test your scenarios and potentially reach out to TIBCO Support.